# Sorting by count using two columns

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

I am outputting some data from mysql into a div, using a php while loop and mysql_fetch_array. Which all works fine but what I am struggling with is.. I want the data to appear ascending from the count of two column rows. but the two columns are in a different table linked by a foreign key (which I set up in phpmyadmin) so at the moment I am:

```
   $query= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM venue WHERE idLocation = $idLocation");
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
      $idVenue = $row['idVenue'];
      $locationName = $row['name'];

      $query_counter_resturant = "SELECT `idResturant` FROM `myTable`
      WHERE `idResturant` = '$venue_id'";
$query_run_counter_resturant = mysql_query($query_counter_resturant);
$counter_resturant = mysql_num_rows($query_run_counter_resturant);

$query_counter_cafe = "SELECT cafe FROM myTable
    WHERE cafe ='$venue_id'";
$query_run_counter_cafe = mysql_query($query_counter_cafe);
$counter_cafe = mysql_num_rows($query_run_counter_cafe);

$counter = $counter_resturant + $counter_cafe;

   ?>
   <div> 
   <p> <?php echo $locationName ?> </p>
   <P> <?php echo $counter ?> </p>
   </div>
```

So basically I want it to be sorted by $counter ascending.. is there anyway to do this?

Comment: You should rewrite your queries to use a single `JOIN`ed query. Then you can do the counting/sorting in SQL directly, instead of having to finagle something together in PHP.

Comment: How are the three (or two) tables related to each other?  You are referencing `myTable` in two of your queries.  What is the real table names?

Comment: You could change your query and/or use arrays to store the results of the queries first. This way you can do some manipulation before printing them. Seems like `idVenue` would be a good choice to use for array index